# Hibernate Entitymanager remove elegantly without exception?

Tags: java, jpa

Is there a more elegant way of avoiding `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException` when calling `EntityManager.remove()` on an object that may or may not currently exist in persistent state? I am trying to avoid a situation where I need to make 2 queries to remove an object. Currently I am cheating with:

```
void remove(String id) {
    T model = entityManager.getReference(type, id);
    entityManager.remove(model);
}
```

But this will throw an exception if the model does not exist.

I could:

```
void remove(String id) {
    T model = retrieve(id);
    if(model != null)
        entityManager.remove(model);
}
```

But that would involve 2 queries (setting aside the notion of a cache for now).

Comment: I vote for catching the exception. Despite what people say, the way sun has programmed the java main api themselves, many times a try-catch during normal execution is absolutely fine. Just the other day I found row 294 in `ClassLoader.loadClass()` try-catching away an expected exception in a *very* core class.

Comment: I suppose an exception is likely just as fast/faster than an additional query on a MySQL db.

Comment: If you have the object reference handy, just call entityManager.contains(obj) - if it returns false, you've already removed it. (this won't work if you only have the ID, or may have had removed it in a different Persistence Context, obviously, in which case a JPQL delete statement would work.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility is to use a Query with a DELETE and a WHERE clause. Works fine, EXCEPT that JPA will not call any @PreDelete or @PostDelete operations on the object to delete. I assume you don't want that anyway, so go with the Query. If you want to call the listeners, the object (obviously) has to be loaded prior deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `select count(*) from ENTITY where id = :id` before remove you entity and then check if the entity exists in database. So you can remove without exception. If you are using a generic DAO with common methods like `find()`, `persist()`, `remove()`... you can add the `count(*)` query in `remove()` method.

Hope it helps.